# Is the concept of Rx debounce possible in a distributed environment?

Tags: distributed-computing, stream-processing, reactive

#### The issue

I am building a server-side system that handles streams of time-series events from multiple users and I'd like to perform an action after a certain quiet period has elapsed in the event stream of every user.

For example, a user emits this stream of data:

```
-[5]------[4]-[3]--[2][1]-->
```

My consumer will handle this stream of data, but will also perform an operation if X time has passed after `[4]` and before `[5]`.

#### Rx?

When looking at the issue [Rx debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) immediately comes to mind.

#### Rx + Multiple consumers?

But is Rx fit for an environment where I run more than one consumer for the streams?

To my understanding, multiple consumers means that individual consumers potentially may be exposed only to parts of the time-series, making it impossible to know when a specific user's stream has started or ended.

For example:

```
USER                         | Application
                             |
-[5]------[4]-[3]--[2][1]--> | ---> [4]--[2]-[1] ---> CONSUMER 1
                             | \
                             |  \-> [5]------[3] ---> CONSUMER 2
```

So can I handle streams with more than one consumer but still harness the power or Rx and debounce? Is there a more fitting solution for this issue?

Comment: If you mean "perform an action after a pause in the stream for **each** user", then the way to approach this is to ensure that any data from a particular user is always handled by the same consumer.

Comment: I think you are overestimating Rx here. Making your application work with Rx for this feature seems more effort than implementing the denounce yourself for this special case. Your own solution also allows you to not keep a thread per user and not tie a user to a consuner

Comment: @marstato It looks like streams are the way to go, but not Rx.
I'm researching Kafka and Redis streams at the moment

Comment: @noamt if you don't have near real time constraints why not leaving it outside RX and delegate to an external process? I.e. https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#flatline

Comment: Help me understand... You have an Observable that emits `-[5]------[4]-[3]--[2][1]-` and you are wondering if you can debounce that observable? Because of course you can...